# React 17.0.2 Functional Component Only Plays CSS Animation on First Render

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I'd like to be able to display text feedback to a user after they answer a question and then fade out the text each time they answer. I'm trying a very simple situation to start out with where I play static feedback after every question. The text between the div is displayed and then fades after the initial rendering of the component but on subsequent renders the text is not displayed and the animation does not occur (I'm using Chrome). I can confirm the component is being re-rendered with Chrome Dev Tools after each cycle and I can see the text in the DOM. I'm using forwards so that at the end of the animation the text will stay invisible. The problem I'm trying to solve is why does the animation only occur after the first render cycle and what do I need to do in order to animate each time the component renders? Other details are that the app uses Redux and all components are functional.

Here's a sandbox that shows what the issue looks like. In this case I passed in props to the feedback component to force it to re-render. Each time you type into the text input it forces the feedback component to re-render (which I confirmed by logging to the console) but the animation only plays on the first render.

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcssanimationissue-zwc6l?file=/src/UserFeedBack/UserFeedBackComponent.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import classes from "./AnswerFeedBackComponent.module.css";
    
    const AnswerFeedBackComponent = () => {          
      
        return (
            <div className={classes.CorrectAnswer} >Correct!</div> 
         );    
    }
    export default AnswerFeedBackComponent;
---
.CorrectAnswer{
    color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
    animation: fade 3s linear forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you produce a minimal sandbox which represents the issue.

Comment: I've posted a link in the problem description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During re-render react looks for only the elements which have changed. If not, then it doesn't update the element, even if it rerenders.

So you can either make react know that this element have changed, or unmount and mount the component again. I have provided both the usecases.

1. You can add a `key` prop with a random value, so that react knows its different on each re-render and hence remounts the component. This is quick and hacky and it works.

```js
const UserFeedBackComponent = (props) => {
  console.log("UserFeedBackComponent rendered");
  const rand = Math.random();

  return (
    <div className={classes.Border} key={rand}>
      <div className={classes.CorrectAnswer}>Correct!</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcssanimationissue-forked-9jufd

2. Another way would be to remove it from the dom after its invisible. The logic will be handled by its parent, `InputComponent`

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import UserFeedBackComponent from "../UserFeedBack/UserFeedBackComponent";
import classes from "./InputComponent.module.css";

const InputComponent = () => {
  const [currentInput, setCurrentInput] = useState("");
  const [showNotification, setShowNotification] = useState(false);

  const inputHandler = (event) => {
    setCurrentInput(event.target.value);
    setShowNotification(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowNotification(false);
    }, 3000);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="text" value={currentInput} onChange={inputHandler} />
      <div className={classes.Output}>{"Output is " + currentInput}</div>
      {showNotification && <UserFeedBackComponent text={currentInput} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default InputComponent;
```

Every time you need to show the notification, you just need to set `showNotification` to `true`, and set it to `false` again via `setTimeout` which will fire after the duration of your animation i.e 3s. This is much better because, there's no stale invisible element, polluting your dom. You can still iterate and improve upon it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcssanimationissue-forked-mejre

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tested the first suggestion with the key and it works as advertised. I had tried something similar by injecting a random number as the text output but that didn't work.

Comment: @HernánGarcia So happy for you!

Comment: Yes! Thank you! the `key` was the best answer for me!